# What is the function of an admin/user namespace controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and would like to know what role an admin/user namespace controller plays in an application. I'm using a book, and I don't quite understand the concept, so please simplify. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace is usually used when you want to separate some part of the app from the rest of the app. It could be the API, admin, or whatever you want. It is used usually to separate big independent parts of the app, like in your case - admin panel.

If you namespace admin, then you would know any URL containing `admin/something` will be meant for the users with admin privileges. It is easier to understand, and also the second benefit is that you could have URL in your app like : `/pages` which would list all the pages, and you could also have `admin/pages` which would list all the pages for admin to manage. You can separate those two controllers in that way.

So the main reason is to have a separate group of controllers that can manage the same or similar group as like the "regular" controllers, but with a different function.